# SQLAlchemy filter query by conditions in multiple table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a Flask webapp and having a hard time with SQLAlchemy.  I am very new to SQLAlchemy and Flask.

I have following three tables.

```
User:
[
   user_id
   first_name
   last_name
]

Picture:
[
   filename
   picture_type // eg: painting, photograph
   painter
]

Comment
[
   user_id
   filename
   comment
]
```

I am trying to query all filenames that was not reviewed by current user.
So the condition would be "all filenames from the picture table with matching picture type where each filename should not have matching, in Comment table, filename and matching user_id with the current user

Currently the current user user_id an picture_type information are available as incoming argument to the function I am trying to write.

How should I write the query using session filter query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Query.join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join). After you joined `Comment` and `Picture` tables on `filename` you can filter them as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the info!!